# python.logging: Why does my non-basicConfig setting not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I want to log to a single log file from main and all sub modules.

The log messages send from a main file, where I define the logger, work as expected. But the ones send from a call to an imported function are missing.

It is working if I use logging.basicConfig as in Example 1 below.
But the second example which allows for more custom settings does not work.

Any ideas why?

```
# in the submodule I have this code
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

**EXAMPLE 1 - Working**

Here I create two handlers and just pass them to `basicConfig`:

```
# definition of root looger in main module

formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s %(name)s.%(levelname)s: %(message)s", datefmt="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")   

handler = logging.FileHandler('logger.log')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler2 = logging.StreamHandler(stream=None)
handler2.setFormatter(formatter)
handler2.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[handler, handler2], level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

**EXAMPLE 2 - Not working**

Here I create two handlers and `addHandler()` them to the root logger:

```
# definition of root looger in main module

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.FileHandler('logger.log')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
#handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(handler)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=None)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: Example 2 *does* work for me (if I copy your `formatter = logging.Formatter(...)` line from the first).  Is there more to this project that could be affecting things?

Comment: You can really see a `module1.DEBUG: test` in the log file and the console? I am not sure what else might cause the problem. I boiled this down from my project to a minimum working example that still shows the behaviour. My first thought was that I am doing something wrong with `logging`'s singleton thing.

Comment: What are you calling to generate log entries?  `logging.warn()` or `logger.warn()`, you should use `logger` (where `warn()` is just a placeholder for any of the logging methods (info, debug, etc).

Comment: Yes, I am using `logger.debug('test')`. Just tested `logging.debug('test')`, also does not show up.

Comment: Can you show your root logger configuration?

Comment: Sure, how? :) Is that a dict?

Comment: Sorry, I was just going from your comment `# definition of root looger in main module`, I thought you set up the root logger in a different file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the (one and only) root logger in the main module of your software. This is done by calling

```
logger = logging.getLogger() #without arguments
```

instead of

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

[(Python doc on logging)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger)

The second example creates a separate, child logger with the name of your script.

If there are no handlers defined in the submodules, the log message is being passed down to the root logger to handle it.

A related question can be found here:
[Python Logging - How to inherit root logger level & handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422689/python-logging-how-to-inherit-root-logger-level-handler)

Comment: Yes, I see `2018.07.01 22:02:04 __main__.DEBUG: got here` (Python 3.4)

Comment: Ok great (it should also appear in the .log file).  So now you've got to figure out what you're doing differently in your code - because you know this works.

Comment: The problem is not the messages I am sending from my main module. They are always there. But I am not getting the ones from modules I import. Could you create a module with some function and see if you can log messages if you call the function from the main module?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer on this, updated question.

Comment: Got it.  In your first example you're configuring the root logger, in the second you're creating a separate, child logger with the name of your script.  If you want to configure the root logger directly, use `logger = logging.getLogger()` instead of `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

Comment: Yep, now it works. But the `%(name)s` in the log now states `root` for the submodule. Is this the same with you?

Comment: It might be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422689/python-logging-how-to-inherit-root-logger-level-handler, will try

Comment: The comment about the root looger is the correct answer. Will you edit your answer or should I do it?

Comment: @Joe, go for it :)  (and make sure to mark it as answer, there's a badge for that, I think)

Comment: Done, the edit should be visible soon. Ok like that?

Comment: @Joe, I thought you meant add your own answer to the question and self check that, but I can "approve" your edit if you want.

Comment: Sure. Your hint, your rep :)

Comment: @Joe, all set, thanks (and happy to help, if just a bit)