# When running __main__.py, get current module

Tags: python, logging, module

I'm creating a program that is executable via the packaged `__main__.py` and installed so I can run it simply as `my_module_name` from the command line. That all is working great.

I'm trying to configure a logger from that `__main__.py` file that is used hierarchically from sub-modules. The loggers in the sub-modules all get their logger by doing:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Which is great because name is `my_module_name.Controllers.A`, etc. I'm looking to setup `my_module_name.Controllers` from `__main__.py`but I cant seem to find `my_module_name` anywhere while I'm debugging and executing `__main__.py` directly. I understand this is kind of funky because python doesn't really execute `__main__.py` as a module... but it's in the `my_module_name` directory.. Is it hacky to just grab that name? Am I going down the right path with this?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using  `logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)` ?

Comment: In the main module you need to configure the root logger, without argument:
`logger = logging.getLogger()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51126605/7919597

Comment: Well the root logger is fine, but I don't want to configure that. I want to configure the logger that is used by all of my controllers - `my_module_name.Controllers` For now I just hard coded the name of the module but that doesn't seem very pythonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR. Yes, you're basically already doing the right thing. :)

You cannot get "current module" when running `__main__.py`. This boils down to difference between module and (module executed as) script (or also "main module") the details of which are described in [PEP-338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/):

> In a main module, the value of `__name__` is always `'__main__'`

There is an extra piece of information in [PEP-366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) regarding relative imports. `__package__` attributed has been introduced. There is also this bit of information:

> When the main module is specified by its filename, then the `__package__` attribute will be set to `None`. To allow relative imports when the module is executed directly, boilerplate similar to the following would be needed before the first relative import statement:
>
> `if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
>       __package__ = "expected.package.name"`

In other words. When being directly called, there module `__name__` is `"__main__"` and `__package__` attribute is `None`, you'd have to set it yourself for (relative imports to work or) any (other) use. You can try to guess, what should it based on `__file__` or if stable, you can just write the name in.