# Python logging calling module from multiple places

Tags: python, logging

I would like to set up a logging hierarchy for my project using python's logging module and the dot '.' name structure described here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger

For a given module (bar.py), I would like to set up the logger something like:

```
log = logging.getLogger('x.bar')
```

Where I can then use log.(debug/info/warning/etc...) throughout the bar.py module. I know that bar.py will never be run directly, but functions within it could possibly be called from several other modules - so I don't know advance what to set 'x' to in the code snippet. I want bar.py to inherit the logging handlers and formatters from it's caller (x).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51126605/7919597

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python.logging: Why does my non-basicConfig setting not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125808/python-logging-why-does-my-non-basicconfig-setting-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach of having a module-wide logger instantiated via `logging.getLogger('mymodule')` is not tailored for your intended behaviour. What you should do instead is to let the callers pass the logger as an argument to the functions in your module

```
# mymodule.py
def foo(plogger, a, b):
    logger=plogger.getChild('bar')
    ...
```