# Python logging from multiple package hierarchies (without using root logger)

Tags: python, logging, packaging

I need to set up logging for a fairly specific setup.  In short, I want to handle logging from a common piece of library code in two different "parent" modules.

```
  app_one \
     app_one_main.py
  app_two \
     app_two_main.py
  lib_package \
     lib_module.py
```

Both *app_one_main* and *app_two_main* import *lib_module* (code below).

These modules obviously do not share the same package structure, so logging messages from lib_module won't propagate up to app_one or app_two by default, if I'm using `getLogger(__name__)`

### Restrictions

- Both *app_one* and *app_two* will be running in the same Python session, so I can't globally manipulate the hierarchy of the logger in *lib_module*.
- I can't manipulate the global root logger because of the way my code is integrated into a larger system.
- *app_one* and *app_two* have different handlers.  For instance, they write their logs to different files.

### Some Ideas

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368859/python-logging-calling-module-from-multiple-places) suggests passing a parent logger into functions of the library code.  This would work, I guess, but it would break almost all of my existing code and I'm not thrilled about passing around loggers this way.
2. I could subclass `logging.Logger` and override `Logger.parent` such that it finds any loggers in its enclosing scopes.  I've implemented something similar in the past, but it seems a bit over-engineered and it would break a lot of features of the default logging system.

### Code

(this code does not even pretend to work.  It's just a rough starting place.)

```
# app_one_main.py

import logging
from lib_package import lib_module

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("APP ONE: %(message)s"))
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

def log_app_one():
    logger.warning("hello from app_one_main")
    lib_module.do_the_thing()
```

```
# app_two_main.py

import logging
from lib_package import lib_module

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("APP TWO: %(message)s"))
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

def log_app_two():
    logger.warning("hello from app_two_main")
    lib_module.do_the_thing()
```

```
# lib_module.py

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def do_the_thing():
    logger.warning("hello from library code")
```

### Desired Result

*app_one* and *app_two* will ultimately run on another platform like Maya, which provides a single python session.  Both modules will be imported into that same session.

So, if I ran `app_one_main.log_app_one()`, I would want:

```
APP ONE: hello from app_one_main
APP ONE: hello from library code
```

And `app_two_main.log_app_two()`:

```
APP TWO: hello from app_two_main
APP TWO: hello from library code
```

Comment: "Both app_one and app_two will be running in the same Python session" What do you mean? Are you running them by virtue of `import`, or are they standalone scripts called by `python appx.py`? If you're running by import you need to restructure the file, importing a module should not have side-effects, i.e. you should be wrapping the logic in a method and in the script case, only invoking the method if `__name__ == "__main__"`

Comment: Can you respond to @flakes question? If these are scripts instead of imported modules, then setting the root logger is the way to go. Generally, imported modules should log to a named logger but its the script's job to setup logging. You could  `getLogger("lib_module")` and configure logging there - but if there are lots of modules, that's not very scalable.

Comment: @flakes They will be run by virtue of being imported into a larger context -- namely, as plugins running in Maya, 3DS Max, or another content creation platform.

Comment: @tdelaney this is also why I can't really use the root logger.  Some of the tools we use already "own" the root and working with it can be very tricky.

I don't know if it's even possible, but I want to be able to just import a module and have its logging go through the handlers in the enclosing scope, potentially multiple (different) enclosing scopes.

Comment: Note - the original question used `logging.Logger()` to create the loggers directly, I meant to use logging.getLogger but missed it.  I've updated the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where I've landed.

### Overview

I'm creating a common logger for all of my tools to use, and a new Filter subclass for handlers that live on it.  The filter ensures that only messages that originated from dependencies of the same parent module as the filter itself will be handled. Theoretically, you could use this Filter class and the stack lookup mechanism on the root logger instead of this "base logger".

## Code

### custom_logging module

The special sauce is in `StackFilter`.  It compares the modules in the current execution stack to one stored on instantiation.  There might be some edge cases where this won't work, but I haven't found them yet.

```
import logging
import inspect

# Loggers
BASE_LOGGER_NAME = "_base_logger_"

def get_base_logger():
    return logging.getLogger(BASE_LOGGER_NAME)

def get_logger(name):
    return logging.getLogger(BASE_LOGGER_NAME + "." + name)


# Filtering
class StackFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = set(enclosing_modules())
        super(StackFilter, self).__init__()

    def filter(self, record):
        calling_stack = set(enclosing_modules())
        return self.stack.issubset(calling_stack)

def enclosing_modules():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()

    frame_count = 0
    _frame = frame
    while _frame:
        frame_count += 1
        _frame = _frame.f_back
    mods = [None] * frame_count

    i = 0
    while frame:
        try:
            mods[i] = frame.f_globals["__name__"]
        except:
            pass
        i += 1
        frame = frame.f_back

    return mods

# Logging Handlers
def add_console_output(formatter=None):
    base_logger = get_base_logger()
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    if formatter:
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.addFilter(StackFilter())
    base_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

The rest of the code is very similar to the original question, but I added a new module to check my work.

### fake_maya/fake_maya_main.py

this will play the part of Maya today, just a place where my various tools will be imported and run.

```
from app_one import app_one_main
from app_two import app_two_main

app_one_main.log_it()
app_two_main.log_it()
```

### app_one/app_one_main.py

```
from lib_package import lib_module
import logging
import custom_logging

logger = custom_logging.get_logger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter("APP ONE: %(message)s")
custom_logging.add_console_output(formatter)

def log_it():
    logger.warning("hello from app_one_main")
    lib_module.do_the_thing()
```

### app_two/app_two_main.py

```
from lib_package import lib_module
import logging
import custom_logging

logger = custom_logging.get_logger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter("APP TWO: %(message)s")
custom_logging.add_console_output(formatter)

def log_it():
    logger.warning("hello from app_two_main")
    lib_module.do_the_thing()
```

### lib_package.lib_module.py

```
import custom_logging

logger = custom_logging.get_logger(__name__)

def do_the_thing():
    logger.warning("hello from library code")
```

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem is that you are instantiating `Logger` objects directly instead of using `getLogger` to get them for you. The [Logger objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects) doc says *Loggers should NEVER be instantiated directly, but always through the module-level function logging.getLogger(name).* When `getLogger` creates a `Logger` it also inserts it into the logging hierarchy so that they can be configured by others. You just have free floating `Logger` objects.

Your library logger is called `lib_package.lib_module`. Once you move to `getLogger` any other module can get the package logger `lib_package`, configure it, and then any of its sub loggers will also work.

**app_one_main.py**

```
import logging
from lib_package import lib_module

# setup logging output for this module
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("APP ONE: %(message)s"))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
#logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

# add handler other modules / packages
pkg_logger = logging.getLogger('lib_package')
pkg_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
#pkg_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
del pkg_logger

logger.warning("hello from app_one_main")
lib_module.do_the_thing()
```

**lib_package/lib_module.py**

```
# lib_module.py

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def do_the_thing():
    logger.warning("hello from library code")
```

Comment: Whoops, that was actually an oversight, I meant to use getLogger from the start.  I will edit the original to reflect that.

One issue with this solution -- what happens when I do the exact same thing in app_two_main.py?  Would lib_module.logger then have two stream handlers?

Comment: Yes. You can verify that with `logging.getLogger('lib_package.lib_module').handlers`. You'll get two logs for everything.

Comment: That's not **really** the behavior I'm after, but it's a good start.  I only want one app_x module's handlers to run at any given time... I'm wondering if maybe an extra filter on the handlers could do the trick.

I'm going to update my original code again to make the use-case a little clearer too

Comment: @EdW - yeah, I was wondering about that. A filter could look down the stack to see which module it came from. or, you could run each app in a different thread and use thread local storage... assuming the modules you call are thread safe. Best of all is if you can get them running as separate processes. I don't know Maya so can't really say.

Comment: definitely good ideas... unfortunately precluded by Maya. I'm going to pursue the filter idea further