# Python logging.basicConfig set different level for handlers

Tags: python, logging

I have the following code for my logging :

```
logging.basicConfig(
                    handlers=[
                        logging.FileHandler("log.txt", "w"),
                        logging.StreamHandler()
                    ],
                    format='%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I would like to set a different level for my 2 handlers. 
**But I realy want to keep it simple, I want to do that with the basicConfig.**

Is there a way I can do that ?

I tried that but it failed :

```
logging.basicConfig(
                    handlers=[
                        logging.FileHandler("log.txt", "w", level=logging.DEBUG),
                        logging.StreamHandler(level=logging.DEBUG)
                    ],
                    format='%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
```

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'

Comment: Yes, you can pass the `level` argument to the two handlers.

Comment: Cool, that's my point. I didn't succeed in doing that

Comment: What happened? Show the code you tried and the error you got.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: You have to create the handler first and call `.setLevel(level)` on it afterward. Using `logging.config.dictConfig()` instead will let you set the level directly in the handler's definition (and is actually more readable IMHO).

Comment: See another question of mine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125808/python-logging-why-does-my-non-basicconfig-setting-not-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're not actually going to use `DEBUG` in practice for the handler levels, as they would pass through all messages (>= `DEBUG`) whether or not you set the level to `DEBUG`. For higher levels, which I have called `level1` and `level2` for illustrative purposes, you could do

```
h1 = logging.FileHandler(...); h1.setLevel(level1)
h2 = logging.StreamHandler(...); h2.setLevel(level2)
```

and then pass `handlers=[h1, h2]` to `basicConfig`.