# How to log serial port input in log file?

Tags: python, serial-port, psychopy

I am using the Psychopy Builder to create an emotion recognition paradigm for fMRI use.

I used a custom code to get a connection with the serial port:

```
import serial
port = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600, timeout=None, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

line = port.readline(2)
```

My question is now, how do I log those informations from the serial port into a log file. Everything else I created within the builder gets logged perfectly in one log file. Its just the serial port input which is missing.

I hope you can help me out!

Comment: Using the Python logging module, look at `FileHandler` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125808/python-logging-why-does-my-non-basicconfig-setting-not-work

Comment: @PsychoStudentOL how are you logging the info you say you're logging correctly atm. Please show that code.